# mysql query depending on other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've *two*  that i want to select from the first table depending on the second table.

First Table

```
ex_instagram_p:

id (int)
username (varchar)
cpc (int)
type (varchar)
active (int)
```

Second Table

```
exchanges

 id (int)
 user (varchar)
 exid (int)
```

What i want :

select values from **ex_instagram_p** and to make sure it does not equal any entry in the second table **exchanges** Where exchanges.user = $username rows Doesn't contains ex_instagram_p.id on exchanges.id

let me clear it

for example table one is for blog articles

so the user will show articles != his username and active = 1 and type ='".follow."'

and the second table is the views.

so if there is an entry on the second table with user = $username and exid = firsttable.id

this entry has been already viewed by this user and i don't want him to view it again.

```
Actually i need if no entry on the exchanges table got the values of
user - exid
$username - i.id

if this doesn't exist is should continue
```

Here is the code i've created, but it does not work

```
$prowz= mysql_query("SELECT i.*
FROM ex_instagram_p as i, exchanges as e
 HAVING COUNT(e.user = '".$username." And e.exid = i.id) = 0 
 WHERE 
 AND i.type = '".follow."' 
 AND i.active=1
 AND i.username != '".$username."'
ORDER BY i.cpc DESC
 LIMIT 1;");
```

Comment: "where" can only appear once. after that it's "and"

Comment: @Strawberry That's [no mistake of Gordon Linoff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851214/mysql-query-select-depending-on-2-tabels).

Comment: @VMai Sorry, I don't follow.

Comment: @Strawberry: The only answer to the question I linked to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851214/mysql-query-select-depending-on-2-tabels#answer-24851292

Comment: `mysql` should be `mysqli`. Just a comment.

Answer (score 0):

`$follow` should be a variable, or just the String `'follow'`. It's an undefined Constant like that.

```
"SELECT i.* FROM ex_instagram_p i, exchanges e
 WHERE i.id != e.exid
 && e.user = '$username'
 && i.type = '$follow'
 && i.active = 1 
 && i.username != '$username'
 ORDER BY i.cpc DESC LIMIT 1;"
```

Comment: i need to use `HAVING COUNT(e.user = '".$username." And e.exid = i.id) = 0 `

Comment: Why, might I ask? I've never seen `COUNT()` used like that before. Are you sure you don't want a subquery?

Comment: Actually i need if no entry on the exchanges table got the values of
user - exid
$username - i.id

if this doesn't exist it should continue

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. user - exid $username - i.id? What does that mean in English?

Comment: i do not know what i really need to use , but what i really need is as following. for example i got two table one for blog topics and the other for topic views. i want to show the user the topics which is for other users only and that he did not view yet only.

Comment: Why don't you change your database structure? A viewed bool could be a column. Your columns that have the same values best be left with the same column names for simplicity.

Answer (score -1):

Many WHERE clauses but it's simple..

```
SELECT i.*
FROM ex_instagram_p as i, exchanges as e
WHERE i.id != e.exid
AND e.user = '".$username."'
AND i.type = '".follow."' 
AND i.active=1
AND i.username != '".$username."'
ORDER BY i.cpc DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Let's not promote 20th C. join conventions OK. So passé

Comment: [Difference between WHERE and JOIN.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)  Each one uses what he wants. And inthis case, both work.

Comment: Actually i need if no entry on the exchanges table got the values of
    user - exid
    $username - i.id

if this doesn't exist is should continue